# Versão recente do django com SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Olá, estou há começar com um projeto onde irei utilizar o framework Django, e devido a natureza do projeto, gostaria de utilizar o SQL Server (pois estou mais familiarizado), porem, tudo que encontro sobre o assunto, diz respeito a versões antigas do Django, neste link https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html está explicito que são necessarias versões antigas do Django, porem, ao procurar pelo site da microsoft, encontrei esse link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/mssql-django-samples/mssql-django-samples/ onde o mesmo mostra como usar o Django com o mssql-django, e ao final da página, encontrei uma referencia da versão do django, e o mesmo está na versão 3.1.8 que não é uma versão muito anterior, e por se tratar de uma publicação do dia  29/04/2021 feita pela microsoft, eu fico na duvida.

Consigo utilizar a versão 3.1.8 do django com o mssql-django? pois gostaria de utilizar uma versão recente com o SQL Server.

Comment: *"Consigo utilizar a versão 3.1.8 do django com o mssql-django?"* já chegou a fazer um teste pra ver se funciona? é uma duvida bem específica, um teste pode ajudar a tirar a duvida

Comment: Ainda não tive tempo, estou pesquisando por parte da manhã, mas como estou no trabalho não tenho muito tempo.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso, para eu conseguir usar o SQL Server utilizei o Django na versão 3.0 e a biblioteca [django-mssql-backend](https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/).

No seu caso, caso opte em utilizar a biblioteca [django-mssql](https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql/), de acordo com a documentação, a versão do Django deve ser a 1.8 e a versão do SQL Server deve ser 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Esqueci de atualizar aqui, eu fiz alguns testes e estou conseguindo utilizar o django na versão 3.2.5 com o mssql-django na versão 1.0rc1 (informada pelo arquivo requirements.txt), até o dado momento não vi nada de incomum ou nenhum bug, está funcionando normalmente.

Espero não encontrar erros futuros por estar usando versões tão recentes.